# How to disable "Document Expired" without using cache

Tags: php, caching, post, get

What I'm doing is simple:
page1 (POST)-> model2 -> Page2 -> Page3

When accessing Page2 by clicking 'Back' button of browser from Page3,
I get "Webpage has expired"(IE) or "Document Expired"(FF) which I don't want to show to users.

As far as I know, one solution is making the "Cache-Control" private or public, 
but I need to generate some one-time key in model2 
which will be posted to Page3(in another site) later.
When back to Page2, the one-time key must be regenerated too,
so cache seems not to be a solution for me.

Using GET to pass parameters from Page1 to Page2 works fine,
the one-time key is regenerated everytime and no warning from the browser
except one little problem : the parameters are shown in the url.
Tried to solve that by using a redirect right after get, 
but that leads back to the cache problem: I can't get the one-time key regenerated.

So is there any way that will not show parameters in url from Page1 to Page2 
and will not show "Document Expired" from Page3 to Page2 when click the 'back' button?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Post them via ajax before you navigate to the next page

Comment: As Page3 is on another site, I can't change the way that one-time key is posted from Page2 to Page3. So I assume that you mean posting parameters via ajax from Page1 to model2(or some other model then pass them to model2 anyway), then use GET to generate one-time key and show Page2. I think that will work, giving a try.

Comment: Well, finally I solved this by "Get one-time key via ajax before navigating to the Page3" and caching Page2.

Comment: So on clicking the submit link on Page2, get the one-time key via ajax, insert/update the key into the form in Page2, use form.submit() to post data and key to Page3.